# Is there any free online dictionary API (json/xml) with multiple languages to choose from?

Tags: translation

Is there any free dictionary API that doesn't require API keys, and allows you to choose between multiple source and destination languages (as many as possible, at least English, German, Spanish, French...)?

Comment: The Merriam-Webster Dictionary API is free as long as it is for non-commercial use, usage does not exceed 1000 queries per day http://www.dictionaryapi.com/.

Comment: I made some simple API for free translation https://github.com/Sangdol/free-and-slow-google-translate-api

Comment: @Ognjen did you ever solve or find a online dictionary API?

Comment: You can try transltr.org it provides free translation api, requires no registration.

Answer (score 36):

You can try http://glosbe.com/a-api , it's big -- almost all languages covered. It allows you to access data in JSON/JSONP/XML. There is some limit set for users without key, but you can overcome it by using JSONP on your client side.

Comment: Any chance you are affiliated with this website?

Comment: Found this answer very helpful for my purposes, but being new I don't understand how you overcome the limitation with JSONP, if it's not too much trouble, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: But I found the results are not accurate.

Comment: Is it free for commercial use?

Comment: Currently API is in it's alpha version and everything described on this page is a subject to change.

Comment: Currently API doesn't work as described. Be requesting for JSON format  it delivers HTML-Content. So I'm unable to create an API key

Comment: In 2022 this API is straight up missing.

Comment: The API documentation page seems to have moved here: https://app.glosbe.com/help/api

But currently it is disabled until further notice :(

Answer (score 15):

I would think that [Wiktionary](http://www.wiktionary.org/) (the dictionary from the folks that originally built Wikipedia) would fit the bill nicely.

**API documentation for Wiktionary**: http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php

Comment: Sadly, everything based on Mediawiki (the most popular wikis) is not designed to be computer readable. It's quite the screw up by the designers of the system.

Comment: Hmmm ... looking at the API docs at the link I gave, it looks like one of the parameters is 'format'.  Apparently you can get output in json, jsonfm, php, phpfm, wddx, wddxfm, xml, xmlfm, yaml, yamlfm, rawfm, txt... and more.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'not designed to be computer readable' if you're referring to something other than returned output format.

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve a JSON, but the content of the page itself is not in JSON format. It's the value of an attribute called "*" and it's usually a plethora of very hard to parse content. The problem is that the API is for all wikis, and all of them are different, so the content can't be easily standardized to make it computer-readable. It's a shame, because that could be an amazing resource. I hope someone does it in the future.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. I've just spent a couple of days trying to parse the "*" attribute broncoAbierto is talking about. It's all a big mess. I've done some version eventually to parse English words definitions. Surprise, the German version has a different format. So I've abandoned this. Pretty sad, really.

Comment: @broncoAbierto -- so sorry to hear that.  That stinks!

Answer (score -3):

Most API providers require registration to prevent denial of service attacks and other abuses.
That being said, I did run across one that is available without registration:

[Aonaware](http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/) - This Web Service allows you to access dictionary definitions from the dict.org service.

Comment: This looks nice. But I have two questions: Is it free to use it in my commercial application? Is there any API for it?

Comment: now its not working