# Faster de-merge of all hashtags

Tags: python, twitter, hashtag

I would like to de-merge hastags from a Twitter dataset. For instance: "#sunnyday" would be "sunny day".

I have found the following code:
The code finds the hastags and looks into  a file called "wordlist.txt", which is a huge txt file with a lot of words for some matching words.

The txt. file can be downloaded here:
[http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/wordlist](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/wordlist)

## Source:  [Term split by hashtag of multiple words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516100/term-split-by-hashtag-of-multiple-words)

#### I modified it a bit to make sure that it works if a sentence is empty: " "

```
# Returns a list of common english terms (words)
def initialize_words():
    content = None
    with open('wordlist.txt') as f: # A file containing common english words
        content = f.readlines()
    return [word.rstrip('\n') for word in content]


def parse_sentence(sentence, wordlist):
    new_sentence = "" # output 
    # MODIFICATION: If the sentence is not empty
    if sentence != '':   
        terms = sentence.split(' ')
        for term in terms:
            # MODIFICATION: If the term is not empty
            if term != '':
                if term[0] == '#': # this is a hashtag, parse it
                    new_sentence += parse_tag(term, wordlist)
                else: # Just append the word
                    new_sentence += term
                new_sentence += " "

    return new_sentence 


def parse_tag(term, wordlist):
    words = []
    # Remove hashtag, split by dash
    tags = term[1:].split('-')
    for tag in tags:
        word = find_word(tag, wordlist)    
        while word != None and len(tag) > 0:
            words.append(word)            
            if len(tag) == len(word): # Special case for when eating rest of word
                break
            tag = tag[len(word):]
            word = find_word(tag, wordlist)
    return " ".join(words)


def find_word(token, wordlist):
    i = len(token) + 1
    while i > 1:
        i -= 1
        if token[:i] in wordlist:
            return token[:i]
    return None
```

The problem is that it takes for ever to run!
**How can I make it faster ?**

Answer (score 0):

Use a `set` instead of a `list` for your `wordlist` variable.

This will be a massive performance improvement because with `list` you need to (potentially) scan the entire word list, so it's `O(n)`. With a `set`, it's `O(1)` because membership is checked by calculating a hash of the item and using that as an index into the backing storage.