# Create a Dictionary iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, dictionary, app-store

I want to create a dictionary app for iPhone. So anybody can suggest that how to create it in best way? 
Is already exists some API that contains all Dictionary words?
How to store all dictionary words in somewhere may be Database or JSON/XML file?
Please suggest

Comment: There is no best way, all answer will based on opinions and all have pros and cons. Also asking for API's is off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: Ok, But what is your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

1: with iOS extensions you can build in dictionary service in the user's iOS keyboard. You have full control of the bottom of the screen. That's a must I think. Dictionary as u type..

2: why store? for dictionary API's look for [Is there any free online dictionary API (json/xml) with multiple languages to choose from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039178/is-there-any-free-online-dictionary-api-json-xml-with-multiple-languages-to-ch)

It's probably in JSON format, REST architecture.