# Javascript English DIctionary Library

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Can anyone suggest me a good javascript library on English Dictionary?.I want to get the meaning of an input word which requires an external library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any free online dictionary API (json/xml) with multiple languages to choose from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039178/is-there-any-free-online-dictionary-api-json-xml-with-multiple-languages-to-ch)

Answer (score 0):

Atom Grammar is a good one. If you're using VS-Code, you can download it from the MS Marketplace.

Github link: [JavaScript Atom Grammar](https://github.com/atom/language-javascript)